# Is it possible to hide the UserControl in Chrome/Firefox for Windows media player?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-media-player

I'm trying to remove the user control (only show the video frame) using Windows Media Player inside Chrome, but without success.

The code I use:

```
<EMBED TYPE="application/x-mplayer2" SRC="..." 
    NAME="MediaPlayer" 
    WIDTH="400" 
    HEIGHT="238" 
    autosize="0" 
    stretchtofit="0" 
    ShowControls="0" 
    ShowStatusBar="0" 
    ShowDisplay="0" 
    autostart="1"> 
</EMBED>
```

But with no success. The control is still visible in Chrome and Firefox, but it works in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

First off, format your code better. It's really annoying having a single long line of code that you need to scroll horizontally to view. Just break it into multiple lines, like:

```
<EMBED
    TYPE="application/x-mplayer2"
    SRC="..."
    NAME="MediaPlayer"
    WIDTH="400"
    HEIGHT="238"
    autosize="0"
    stretchtofit="0"
    ShowControls="0"
    ShowStatusBar="0"
    ShowDisplay="0"
    autostart="1"
></EMBED>
```

You should also use [`OBJECT`](http://joliclic.free.fr/html/object-tag/en/) instead of `EMBED`, as `EMBED` is not a standard tag. And, according to [this page](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial152_Embedding-Windows-Media-Player-into-a-web-page.html), you need to specify a `CLASSID` parameter to embed the latest version of WMP. Then you need a `uiMode` param that tells WMP not to display the controls:

```
<OBJECT id="VIDEO" CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"
    type="application/x-oleobject" width="320" height="240">
    <PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="MyVideo.wmv">
    <PARAM NAME="enabled" VALUE="True">
    <PARAM NAME="AutoStart" VALUE="False">
    <PARAM name="PlayCount" value="3">
    <!-- ...other params... -->
    <PARAM name="uiMode" value="none">
</OBJECT>
```

Other options for `uiMode` include `full`, `mini`, and `invisible`.

**Edit:**
I personally prefer Quicktime/.mov over WMP/.wmv for embedding streaming video online, but the best cross-platform solution is to embed a Flash player and encode your video as an FLV. WMP/.wmv would be one of my last choices for embedding multimedia on a webpage (next to RealPlayer). According to [this site](http://elearningtech.blogspot.com/2007/10/video-format-comparison-flash-wmv.html), WMP browser plugin usage has dropped down to 67% since January (when it was at 72%), whereas Flash support has remained steady at 96-97%.

Comment: Thanks. I will give object/uiMode a try.

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot to add this link where I got the info about `uiMode` from: http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial152_Embedding-Windows-Media-Player-into-a-web-page.html

Comment: Could it be that object doesn't work in Firefox and that I need to do a fallback using embed? couildn't get object to work in firefox :(